# My prefix is the result of a collision

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is the result of a collision,
>
> my suffix is cancelled with rescission.
>
> My infix aids my television,
>
> overall, I am played with precision.

**What am I?**

Comment: @downvoter why did this get a downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you a

> RECORDER?

My prefix is the result of a collision,

> That's a mighty nasty (w)REC(k) you got there!

my suffix is cancelled with rescission.

> Official ORDERs are cancelled by rescission.

My infix aids my television,

> Hard to watch TV without CORDs.

overall, I am played with precision.

> *Oh god Grade 5 flashbacks save us now!*

Comment: Correct! Love your answers :)

Comment: Thanks @casey! Nice to see another local on Puzzling.SE! I've thoroughly enjoyed your puzzles :D

Comment: _Further edit: Also way to rep Durham Region!! :D_